# Why are chemical reactions the same at different gravity levels?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, physical-chemistry

Are all chemical reactions the same at a quantum level in different levels of gravity? How does the mass of subatomic particles change atomic behaviour at different gravity, in terms of speed and trajectory? What is the difference in between changing temperature and gravity coefficients?

Comment: That is indeed a very interesting question. Unfortunately there is no corresponding quantum theory of gravity, so we don't know the answer. Our theory for elementary particles, the standard model, is only valid when we can neglect gravity (which in most observable environments is the case).